# Moving special lines on cubic threefold

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a cubic hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^4$. $F(X)$ variety of lines on $X$.

In this [survey](http://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/CoursRome.pdf) on page 3 Debarre claims that $F(X)$ is connected. Moreover he says that there are two type of lines (points in $F(X)$).

I construct an explicit family of lines of the second type.

$$X = \{ (x_0 : x_1 : x_2 : x_3: x_4) | x_0^3 + x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 + x_4^3= 0 \} $$

My lines are parametrized by elliptic curve $E = \{ (a_1: a_2 : a_3) | a_1^3 +a_2^3 +a_3^3 = 0 \}$

My family of lines is defined as follows

$$ l_a  = \{ ( \mu : -\mu : a_1 \nu : a_2 \nu : a_3 \nu ) \ \  \text{for all} \ \ (\mu : \nu) \in \mathbb{P}^1 \} $$

All curves from from this family intersect at one point. Then normal bundle has subsheaf $\mathcal{O} (1)$. Then all these curves are of second type (because $\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} $ does not have $\mathcal{O}(1)$ as a subsheaf ).

**Question** How can one move line from my family to get a general line? Such movement must be possible from connectedness of $F(X)$, must not it?

Comment: Your equation for $X$ defines a cubic surface in $\mathbf P^3$. I guess you left out a variable.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question.